# How to get the number of the most frequent value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, counter, frequency, series

I have a data frame and I would like to know how many times a given column has the most frequent value.

I try to do it in the following way:

```
items_counts = df['item'].value_counts()
max_item = items_counts.max()
```

As a result I get:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

As far as I understand, with the first line I get series in which the values from a column are used as key and frequency of these values are used as values. So, I just need to find the largest value in the series and, because of some reason, it does not work. Does anybody know how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Are there `na`'s in your column? If so you should get rid of them with `dropna` or `fillna`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It looks like you may have some nulls in the column. You can drop them with `df = df.dropna(subset=['item'])`. Then `df['item'].value_counts().max()` should give you the max counts, and `df['item'].value_counts().idxmax()` should give you the most frequent value.

Comment: And... can I do it so that NA is counted as a value? I.e. I am happy to return NA if that is the most common value.

Comment: @FullDecent use `.fillna()` instead of `.dropna()`

Comment: If I want to find the second most maximum value, how to do that?

Comment: use `df['item'].value_counts().nlargest(n=2).iloc[[2]]`

Comment: df['item'].value_counts().nlargest(n=2)..iloc[[1]].index[0]

Answer (score 19):

To continue to @jonathanrocher answer you could use [`mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) in pandas DataFrame. It'll give a most frequent values (one or two) across the rows or columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,2,4,2], "b": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 3]})

In [2]: df.mode()
Out[2]: 
   a    b
0  2  3.0
```

Comment: Hi, could you take a look at this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70954791/identifying-statistical-outliers-with-pandas-groupby-and-reduce-rows-into-diffe

Answer (score 13):

You may also consider using scipy's `mode` function which ignores NaN. A solution using it could look like:

```
from scipy.stats import mode
from numpy import nan
df = DataFrame({"a": [1,2,2,4,2], "b": [nan, nan, nan, 3, 3]})
print mode(df)
```

The output would look like

```
(array([[ 2.,  3.]]), array([[ 3.,  2.]]))
```

meaning that the most common values are `2` for the first columns and `3` for the second, with frequencies `3` and `2` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Just take the first row of your `items_counts` series:

```
top = items_counts.head(1)  # or items_counts.iloc[[0]]
value, count = top.index[0], top.iat[0]
```

This works because [`pd.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) has `sort=True` by default and so is *already ordered* by counts, highest count first. Extracting a value from an index by location has O(1) complexity, while [`pd.Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) has O(*n*) complexity where *n* is the number of categories.

Specifying `sort=False` is still possible and then `idxmax` is recommended:

```
items_counts = df['item'].value_counts(sort=False)
top = items_counts.loc[[items_counts.idxmax()]]
value, count = top.index[0], top.iat[0]
```

Notice in this case you don't need to call `max` and `idxmax` separately, just extract the index via `idxmax` and feed to the `loc` label-based indexer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code to find the most frequent value

```
df["item"].value_counts().nlargest(n=1).values[0]
```

Comment: df["item"].value_counts().nlargest(n=1).index[1]

Answer (score 1):

The NaN values are omitted for calculating frequencies. 
[Please check your code functionality here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8zsO.png)
But you can use the below code for same functionality.

```py
**>> Code:**
    # Importing required module
    from collections import Counter

    # Creating a dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A':["jan","jan","jan","mar","mar","feb","jan","dec",
                             "mar","jan","dec"]  }) 
    # Creating a counter object
    count = Counter(df['A'])
    # Calling a method of Counter object(count)
    count.most_common(3)

**>> Output:**

    [('jan', 5), ('mar', 3), ('dec', 2)]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: In addition to the above comment, yours is the only non-Pandas solution so it would be good for you to explain how this solution helps and how it handles the OP's NaN problem.